# When using pd.rolling_max, how can I assign a particular value within the data frame as the window value?

Tags: python, pandas

the column max should be the max in a range.

```
if df['y'] >= 1: #then use y as the window...
```

currently using:

```
df['max'] = None
df['max'][df['y']>1] = pd.rolling_max(df['y'], window = df['y']
```

result is:

> TypeError: cannot convert the series to type 'int'

```
    x    y    max
A   1    1
B   1    0
C   1    0
D   1    3
```

would like it to be:

```
    x    y    max
A   1    1    1
B   1    0
C   1    0
D   1    3    3
```

help would be appreciated.  thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing isn't a max over a rolling window.  If it were, when `y` is `3` in row `D`, you'd be missing 2 more rows to include in the rolling window.  I think you are just after a max of the elements in the row, when `df.y >= 1`.  In this case:

```
df['max'] = df.loc[df.y >= 1].apply(max, axis=1)

print df

   x  y  max
A  1  1  1.0
B  1  0  NaN
C  1  0  NaN
D  1  3  3.0
```